# Mongo object's id as dirname for file upload in Sinatra/Mongoid

Tags: ruby, mongodb, post, sinatra, mongoid

I'm working on Sinatra site which allows user to upload files. I got this action route:

```
post '/upload' do
  params.delete 'submit'
  UsrUpld.new(
    :name       => params[:name]
    :created_at => Time.now
  ).save
  params[:photos].each do |photo|
    File.open('public/uploads/' + UsrUpld.id + '/' + photo[:filename], 'w') do |file|
      file.write(photo[:tempfile].read)
    end
  end
  redirect '/index'
end
```

I think this should create document in MongoDB with two fields *name* and *created_at*, the take file from POST request and write it in *public/uploads/ID/FILE.jpg*. But Pow returns me **undefined method `id' for UsrUpld:Class**. How to ask object's id in route with Mongoid?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: When I'm trying to upload file without *UsrUpld.id* it works fine and saves all files in the /uploads. Also I tried create *u* variable with new *UsrUpld* inside, this returns same **undefined method `id'**.

Comment: Oh, I understood: I'm asking for *id* *UsrUpld.new(# code).save*, instead *UsrUpld.new*, now I'm doing *u = UsrUpld.new* and then *u.save*, exactly as you pointed.

Comment: If you've found the answer to your question, feel free to post it as an answer below. You'll be able to mark it accepted in the next day or so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To ask an id, object should placed in variable which should contain exactly this object, so code should look like this:

```
post '/upload' do
  params.delete 'submit'
  u = UsrUpld.new(
    :name       => params[:name],
    :created_at => Time.now
  )
  u.save
  params[:photos].each do |photo|
    unless File.exists?('public/media/' + u.id)
      Dir.mkdir('public/media/' + u.id)
    end
    File.open('public/uploads/' + u.id + '/' + photo[:filename], 'w') do |file|
      file.write(photo[:tempfile].read)
    end
  end
  redirect '/index'
end
```

Also dir should exist before opening the file, thats why *Dir.mkdir* line added.